# Jumble word game written in Java using a random number generator non-deterministically gets the user stuck in an infinite loop. How to fix?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I was given instructions to program a jumble word game in Java last semester, as an assignment. My instructor said I could post this on stackoverflow after the due date for the assignment had expired, so nothing here is unauthorized outside help (aka cheating). A good description of the program is as follows:

This program reads from a file of a long list of words, randomly selects one of those words, then randomly jumbles one of those words. The user will then see the jumbled word,
and see a menu that allows them to either take a guess, get a hint, get a new word, or quit. Each new word gives a possible 10 points, but guessing incorrectly and getting hints
will decrease the total number of possible points the user can get from guessing the word correctly.

If the total number of possible points reaches zero for a word,
the program will generate a new word for the user. If the user guesses the word correctly, the program will congratulate them, and display the number of points gained
from that word, as well as the user's total score. Upon the exit of the program by the user, the program will display the final score of the user for that specific run.

The file that has the list of words that I used is called words.txt, and it looks like this:

[screenshot of 'words.txt'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoJAf.png)

The first line is the number of words in the file. I use that to define the array size.

Everything about the program works fine, except that sometimes when I play the game over and over again, I will get stuck in an infinite loop. The worst part is, there's no apparent pattern to the infinite loops, save for the fact that the infinite loop always occurs after the program identifies the word to be jumbled. But other than that, there is no easy pattern to see.

I asked my instructor for help, and he said he didn't find anything that jumped out to him that was obviously faulty code-wise. He said he could've found out the problem if he stared at it for hours, but he didn't have that much time. Since he couldn't find out what was the with the code itself, he let me submit my code without penalty for this weird bug. I remember getting a perfect score on the assignment.

Sometimes the bug will manifest itself in the first few iterations of the program:

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4XG3.png)

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNhDN.png)

But sometimes it will take longer for the bug to manifest:

[Example3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJopZ.png)

Here is the computer program that I wrote:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proj5{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randGen = new Random();

    System.out.print("Enter in text file containing words (Ex: words.txt): ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    String line = s.nextLine();
    int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(line);

    String [] WordList = new String [arraySize];

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
      WordList[i] = s.nextLine();
    }

    s.close();

    boolean OuterExitValue = true;

    int totalScore = 0;

    while(OuterExitValue){

    int RandomWord = randGen.nextInt(WordList.length);

    String CorrectWord = WordList[RandomWord];

    int RandomN, k = 0, i = 0;

    System.out.print("Word = " + CorrectWord);

    char [] JumbledWord = new char [CorrectWord.length()];
    boolean [] check = new boolean [CorrectWord.length()];

    while( i < CorrectWord.length() ) {

      RandomN = randGen.nextInt(CorrectWord.length());

      if ( !(check[RandomN % CorrectWord.length()]) ) {

        JumbledWord[RandomN % CorrectWord.length()] = CorrectWord.charAt(i);
        //System.out.println(JumbledWord[i]);
        check[RandomN % CorrectWord.length()] = true;
        i++;

      }

      if ( i == CorrectWord.length() ){

        for(int j = 0; j < CorrectWord.length(); j++){

          if( JumbledWord[j] == CorrectWord.charAt(j) )
            k++;
        }

      }

      if ( k == CorrectWord.length() ) {

          i = 0;

          for(int j = 0; j < CorrectWord.length(); j++){
            check[j] = false;
          }

        }

    }

    System.out.println();

    int NPoints = 10;
    String guess = "a";
    boolean InnerExitValue = true;

    while(InnerExitValue){

      System.out.print("Current puzzle: ");

      for (i = 0; i < CorrectWord.length(); i++)
        System.out.print(JumbledWord[i]);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent points for word: " + NPoints);
        System.out.print("Enter (g)uess, (n)ew word, (h)int, or (q)uit: ");
        char option = keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        switch (option) {

          case 'q':
            InnerExitValue = false;
            OuterExitValue = false;
            System.out.println("\nThanks for Playing! Goodbye!");
            System.out.println("Final score: " + totalScore);
            System.exit(0);
            break;

          case 'h':
            int RandomLetter = randGen.nextInt(CorrectWord.length());
            int RandomSpot = RandomLetter + 1;
            System.out.println("\nThe letter at spot " + RandomSpot + " is " + CorrectWord.charAt(RandomLetter) + "\n" );
            NPoints = NPoints/2;
            break;

          case 'g':

            System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
            guess = keyboard.next();

            if ( !(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(CorrectWord)) ) {
              NPoints -= 1;
              System.out.println("Sorry, try again.\n");
            }
            else{
              totalScore += NPoints;
              System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed it!");
              System.out.println("Score for word: " + NPoints);
              System.out.println("Total score: " + totalScore);
              System.out.println();
              InnerExitValue = false;
            }
            break;

          case 'n':
            InnerExitValue = false;
            System.out.println();
            break;

          default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice - 'g', 'n' 'h' or 'q' only.\n");
        }

        if(NPoints == 0){
          System.out.println("Word points = 0. Generating a new word");
          InnerExitValue = false;
        }


      }

    }

}
}
```

I tried some things out with my code. I used traces to find out where my code was getting stuck in an infinite loop, and it turns out that the infinite loop is always occurring in the first while loop that has the purpose of jumbling a word and checking that it's jumbled properly. I added this trace at the bottom of the first while loop, right before the bracket, where I just inputted:

```
for(int m = 0; m < CorrectWord.length(); m++)
          System.out.print(JumbledWord[m]);
```

This trace allowed me to see what jumbled word is being seen by the computer before it becomes a properly jumbled word that the user can deal with. This allowed me to see this:

[Program output with trace in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B7jA.png)

If you look carefully, you can see that every 'current puzzle' is just the last four or five sequence of characters in that jumbled mess of letters. Presumably, this means the last sequence is being grabbed by the computer to become the 'current puzzle', which is in line with the logic inside my program, so that's a good sign that the program is working as intended. So what about using this trace to find what an infinite loop will look like?

Here is another screenshot:

[Program output with trace showing infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nePk.png)

In the above image, we see the program jumbling the word, but for some reason, the w character becomes more, and more frequently printed to the screen compared to all the other ones, and then it just keeps being printed to the screen indefinitely. But that is not something I expect to see given my code. I suspect there is a teeny tiny error in the algorithm that I concocted. It seems that the program occasionally jumbles words in a way that leaves out essential letters that need to be in that sequence of characters in order for the word to be correctly jumbled. We can see the same phenomena with this other screenshot:

[Program output with trace showing infinite loop 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewPC5.png)

In both pictures, one letter is being oddly left out with the first couple of 'jumbles.' For the last picture, it is 'd' and for the second to last picture, it is 'k'. This may be a hint that with my algorithm, I am not actually 'jumbling' letters, instead I am copying and pasting letters into certain indexes, inevitably resulting in odd cases where at least one letter is just 'pasted' over or overwritten by other letters, never appearing again. I am not sure that this decisively solves the issue for me, though.

Comment: You may want to read about the Fisher-Yates algorithm for shuffling. Look it up.

Comment: Your problem is with the `if ( k == CorrectWord.length() )` case. In this case you are setting `i` to 0 and not changing `k`, so `k` will remain at the word length. This means every time through the loop you will again get into this `if` statement and set `i` back to 0, which prevents you from ever getting out of the loop.

Comment: @OleV.V. 
Ah ha! Bingo! Thank you so much for pointing that out. Now it appears my program works just fine!